Traffic simulation with collision detection on multiple curves
This is for a project I already posted here about.
older question about same project
I'm creating a traffic simulation in geometry nodes.
First I turn the original curve object into 6 parallel tracks, then I spawn points on them and move the points along the tracks using the simulation zone.


The next step is to create a collision detection system that stops the moving points when they get too close to target geometry, and then other points following behind them. Each subsequent point is stopped when it gets close to the previous stopped point. I already have a similar working simulation, which I've used as a template.


This node tree works with points moving in a straight line on a single axis. Converting it to work on a curve wasn't too difficult, but the real problem with it that after stopping a point, it selects the next point to stop based on its index, and with points spawned randomly on 6 tracks, the points following each other don't have following indices.
I would need to find a way to stop the points moving along individual tracks when a specific track is blocked, then stop the following points, and preferably also stop spawning new points on a blocked track.
Both the traffic simulation and the template simulation are included in the file.

It seems to me, inevitably your traffic simulation will require intersections, which can't be done with curves. So why spend time on improving the project with this foundation flaw that sets it up for failure further down the line?

@MarkusvonBroady I'm not the only person working on this project. I just need to finish this one thing and then it's out of my hands. As far as I know this is the last part of the project that depends on geometry nodes. I referred to it as my project because it's simpler to explain that way.

I think you can explore the few nodes in Curve > Topology especially Points of Curve that can help you group your points per Spline, then you "just" have to find a way to find the closest point on this spline in a given direction (towards start or towards end), rinse and repeat

Can we assume that the length of the animation is limited (at 250 frames e.g.) and that per frame, only one new point is added to one of the tracks ?

@StefLAncien yes

Here's the basic principle: use "Geometry Proximity" against a collider to decide if a vehicle is supposed to stop. If it is, then move the vehicle to the collider.
For a simpler setup and less memory usage, I'm using ID and Radius to store information (distance traveled and path index). You could actually also use the point position to store information, because its position is completely determined from curve sampling, but then the setup would get a little bit more complex. Similarly with slowing the vehicles smoothly or using a low poly (bounding boxes?) versions of vehicles for the collider (in such case you wouldn't display the collider and also add the instances of real vehicles to 3rd geometric output).



it's not working for me, I'm not getting any points.

@Lynx095 show a screenshot of your setup

how do I add pictures to comments?

@Lynx095 comments are supposed to be short-lived so you can just upload to imgur.

https://imgur.com/a/3dd5Wdx
https://imgur.com/a/htgipTT

@Lynx095 You enabled "Skip" in your simulation :D

changed it, I have the points now but the collision still isn't working.

@Lynx095 you override the Geometry Proximity position with the collider object location, which you shouldn't do

in your screenshot the geometry proximity node has no position input. I assumed that was mistake. I fixed it, now how do I unblock the tracks? In my original simulation I only needed to move the cube out of the way to do that.

@Lynx095 you can't.  Not in this setup.

then it doesn't help me.

@Lynx095 well you never mentioned this in your question, I would address it otherwise.

Well, I talk about it as a traffic simulation. Also in my file, the template animation works that way for points moving on the X axis and my adapted version works that way for a single curve, and I say that I need the same functionality for multiple curves.

@Lynx095 let me quote myself from under the question: "It seems to me, inevitably your traffic simulation will require intersections, which can't be done with curves. So why spend time on improving the project with this foundation flaw that sets it up for failure further down the line?" - you answered however, that it's not a problem because you just need this. And now turns out it actually is a problem. The file is not a part of the question on BSE, it's a complimentary addition to make it easier to answer if someone doesn't want to create a setup from scratch.

That's not what the problem is, I already got it working for a single curve. Also, you can just ignore this question so that someone else can solve it.
